# snakemake with multiple wildcards, one regular and other dynamic

Tags: snakemake

I have input files that looks like:

```
93965_0_0_16000_16000.tif
93965_0_16000_16000_12799.tif
93965_16000_0_14548_16000.tif
93965_16000_16000_14548_12799.tif
93966_0_0_16000_16000.tif
93966_0_16000_16000_3800.tif
93966_16000_0_2980_16000.tif
93966_16000_16000_2980_3800.tif
93967_0_0_16000_16000.tif
93967_0_16000_16000_12799.tif
93967_16000_0_16000_16000.tif
93967_16000_16000_16000_12799.tif
93967_32000_0_2365_16000.tif
93967_32000_16000_2365_12799.tif
94297_0_0_16000_16000.tif
94297_0_16000_16000_16000.tif
94297_0_32000_16000_16000.tif
94297_0_48000_16000_7799.tif
94297_16000_0_16000_16000.tif
94297_16000_16000_16000_16000.tif
94297_16000_32000_16000_16000.tif
```

the output will be:

```
6000_16000_14548_12799.png
93966_0_0_16000_16000.png
93966_0_16000_16000_3800.png
93966_16000_0_2980_16000.png
93966_16000_16000_2980_3800.png
93967_0_0_16000_16000.png
93967_0_16000_16000_12799.png
93967_16000_0_16000_16000.png
93967_16000_16000_16000_12799.png
93967_32000_0_2365_16000.png
93967_32000_16000_2365_12799.png
94297_0_0_16000_16000.png
94297_0_16000_16000_16000.png
94297_0_32000_16000_16000.png
94297_0_48000_16000_7799.png
94297_16000_0_16000_16000.png
94297_16000_16000_16000_16000.png
94297_16000_32000_16000_16000.png
```

So, the first part is a unique ID, the remaining part varies. I want to group many inputs/output by the first unique ID. So, one wild card is to be treated normally, and the other need special method to expand it that I am looking for.

I have the following so far

```py
rule process:
    input: 
        '{id}_{patch}.tif'
    output:
        './output_{id}_{patch}.png'
    wildcard_constraints:
        patch = "\d+_\d+_\d+_\d+.*"
    shell:
         """
         bash command {wildcard.id}
         """
```

I tried to make regex rule in input and output to filter the list, but seems snakemake does not evaluate the input/output this way.

I expect each job to run on a list of the same id, but different patch.

I appreciate any ideas.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone else can come up with a more elegant solution.

```
IDS, PAT1, PAT2, PAT3, PAT4, = glob_wildcards("{id}_{pat1}_{pat2}_{pat3}_{pat4}.tif")

PATCHES = list(zip(PAT1,PAT2,PAT3,PAT4))

patches = []
for i in PATCHES:
    string = "_".join(i)
    patches.append(string)

rule all:
    input:
        expand("{id}_{patch}.png", zip, id = IDS, patch = patches)

rule process:
    input:
        "{id}_{patch}.tif"
    output:
        "{id}_{patch}.png"
    shell:
        """
        echo {wildcards.id} > {output}
        """
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. But I think this will still run the jobs file by file, right? I want same ID to be executed only one.

Comment: This solution can identify the uniq ID and the Patch. Can you can clarify what you mean with "same ID to be executed only one"?

Comment: lets say image id "94297". I want to create input and output that would dynamically create ['94297_16000_32000_16000_16000.png','94297_16000_16000_16000_16000.png', ...  ] for each id. So for each job executed, the input and output are multiple files, but with single ID